# Why Wasserstein GAN (WGAN) is not widely used compared to DCGAN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Wasserstein GAN (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875) is a big improvement to DCGAN for better training stability and less model collapse. But when seeing the implementations, WGAN is remarkably less used than the original DCGAN. 
What is the cause of this fact?

Comment: Not a programming question, so off-topic. Seems better suited to Quora, for example Either way, I would disagree. Many breakthrough GAN papers (e.g. StyleGAN) use a Wasserstein loss. You would have to specify what you mean by "the implementations".

Comment: @xdurch0 [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for this question but because it’s implementation related, it’s not necessarily "not a programming question".

Comment: why to close the question. I am asking for an implementation related question. Which are the facts that decrease the implementation of WGAN is real case scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have a definitive answer but one possibility is simply ease of use and open source implementations. A quick search shows a Pytorch implementation of WGAN and a TensorFlow tutorial on DCGAN. TensorFlow was previously the more popular option (according to this [link](https://thegradient.pub/state-of-ml-frameworks-2019-pytorch-dominates-research-tensorflow-dominates-industry/)) so people probably opted for the simpler option when implementing a comparison.

Also, bear in mind a stable implementation where you know you’ve probably implemented it correctly and your competing technique surpasses it is more desirable than learning a new framework for a GAN that will be harder to beat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. really what I want.